# Read console output of a shell script in Perl

Tags: perl, shell, unix, console, log4perl

Let's say I've got a shell script called `print_error.sh` looking like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "ERROR: Bla bla, yada yada."
exit 1
```

Now I'm in a Perl script, calling this shell script with

```
system("print_error.sh")
```

I now want to read the console output of `print_error.sh` and write it to a [Log4perl](http://mschilli.github.com/log4perl/) logger.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not to be off-topic, but wouldn't it be easier to print the error in perl directly? Or write `print_error.sh` in perl (`print_error.pl`) and `require` it? No point in using external commands to do something that perl does much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I've found:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Log::Log4perl;

my $logfile = "log.txt";
$ENV{"LOGFILE"} = $logfile;

Log::Log4perl->init("log4perl.properties");
$logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();

$logger->info("pos 1");
system("./print_error.sh 0 2>&1 >> $logfile") == 0
        or die "perl error";
$logger->info("pos 2");

exit 0
```

See also [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can%27t-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system%28%29?).

Answer (score 5):

Either use backticks:

```
my $results = `print_error.sh`;
```

or see open:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Comment: Can I somehow get the exit code of the shell script too with the backticks?

Comment: Check the value of $?:
`my $retval = $?`

Comment: Also, note the qx operator.  my $results = qx( print_error.sh )   Why is print_error.sh writing to stdout instead of stderr?